# The result of multiple test methods in Junit is different when each method is run on its own

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have 3 test methods in a  test class. When I run each one on its own it has a successful result but whenever I run all three, only one of the test methods has a successful result with the others showing errors of elements not found ( I'm using Selenium ). I can't understand why that happens knowing that the methods are independent.

Comment: Please post the code. Only that will be helpful

Comment: Are all of the tests performing actions on the same objects? If so, one test could change the state of the object in such a way that the following tests fail unless you clean up after each test properly.

Comment: The setup/teardown or @Before/@After methods does not a correct cleanup of the test environment between the different methods.